# Why does $K_{\chi(H)}(|H|)$ contain the graph H?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Why does $K_{\chi(H)}(|H|)$ necessarily contain the graph H? This is part of the more general question as to why $K_{\chi(H)}(t)$ should contain H for sufficiently large t.
Here $K_{r}(t)$ is a complete r-partite graph with t vertices in each vertex class.

Comment: By $K_{n}(m)$ you mean the blow-up of $K_{n}$ where each vertex class has $n$ vertices?  You may want to add this to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to find a copy of $H$ in $K_{\chi(H)}(|H|)$:

Label each of the vertex classes of $K_{\chi(H)}(|H|)$ as $V_{1},...,V_{\chi(H)}$.  Start by coloring the vertices of $H$ with $\chi(H)$ colors (proper coloring), i.e. colors $\{1, 2, 3, ..., \chi(H)\}$.  Map each color to a vertex class, and map each vertex that is colored with that color to a distinct vertex in the class.  I.e. every vertex that is colored $i$ gets mapped to a distinct vertex in $V_{i}$.  This can be done since $H$ can be colored with $\chi(H)$ colors and no more that $|H|$ vertices get mapped to any one class $V_{i}$.  Now, the vertices that you've mapped to form a complete $\chi(H)$-partite graph.  So every edge possible is there (except edges between vertices of the same color), but you know in $H$ vertices of the same color did not have an edge between them to begin with.

Comment: @a.e. This is the idea.  With a little more care you can write out a careful proof.  I was mostly hoping to point you in the right direction and convince you that it is true.

Comment: Of course- I was trying to fit in $K_{|H|}$ (hence H) into the graph, which is not possible, rather than trying to fit H itself directly. Thanks.